# What's the recommended way to pass non-serializable options from Nuxt module options to a Nitro event handler?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm making a Nuxt module that has some methods defined in the module's options. I can use these options to set up the module itself but I'm unsure how to pass these options to the Nitro event handler used by the module.

I could [pass module options to the runtime config](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/modules#exposing-options-to-runtime), which is available in the Nitro server, but since [module options are serialized](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config#serialization) before Nuxt passes them to the Nitro server this won't work.

What's the best way to pass these types of options (functions or anything that can't be easily serialized) to the Nitro server? Or am I going about this the wrong way?